# delphi Get and compare big text file from web with string

Tags: delphi

I have one big text file with 95000+ lines on web

Now for example:

- I have one string
- I want to match that string in that file 
  and read that whole line where that string is placed in file

I am using wininet
I can load whole file in to string
but while matching it takes alot of time and gui hangs

is there anyway to do it more faster ?

**edit:**

**Here is code i m using to get urlcontents from web**

**in button1**

```
var
s:string;

begin
  //1-  as file is big it takes alot of time :/ 
  S := GetUrlContent('web url example');
  if (Pos('string i want to search', s)> 0) then
  begin 
  mmo1.lines.add('Found');
  //2-  now how can i show extact line that contains string 
  end;
end;
```

//----------------------------------------------------

```
function GetUrlContent(const Url: string): string;
var
  NetHandle: HINTERNET;
  UrlHandle: HINTERNET;
  Buffer: array[0..1024] of Char;
  BytesRead: dWord;
begin
  Result := '';
  NetHandle := InternetOpen('Delphi 5.x', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);

  if Assigned(NetHandle) then
  begin
    UrlHandle := InternetOpenUrl(NetHandle, PChar(Url), nil, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);

    if Assigned(UrlHandle) then
      { UrlHandle valid? Proceed with download }
    begin
      FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), 0);
      repeat
        Result := Result + Buffer;
        FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), 0);
        InternetReadFile(UrlHandle, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BytesRead);
      until BytesRead = 0;
      InternetCloseHandle(UrlHandle);
    end
    else
      { UrlHandle is not valid. Raise an exception. }
      raise Exception.CreateFmt('Cannot open URL %s', [Url]);

    InternetCloseHandle(NetHandle);
  end
  else
    { NetHandle is not valid. Raise an exception }
    raise Exception.Create('Unable to initialize');
end;
```

Comment: Does it have to match exactly (case sensitive)? Are you restricted to downloading the file via WinInet? What have you tried?

Comment: @MarcusAdams yes its case sensitive and no its not restricted i dont know anyother way of downloading to string - thx

Comment: Don't download it. Do the comparison server side.

Comment: sorry my bad 
i dont download it just get directly url contents to string

Comment: Make a web service with a method through which you'll pass the string to find and which returns you the line number. But anyway, this smells like some sort of a catalog stored in a single file. If that is so, move those lines into a database if you can.

Comment: Moving 95000+ lines to database will take lot of time :/
is there any other way of getting all text faster and comparing ?

Comment: We can't show you faster until you show us what you've tried.

Comment: @MarcusAdams pls check now first post all is explained with code now 
what i want to do  :)

Comment: @dudey: `Result := Result + Buffer` is wrong logic to use. `Buffer` is empty on the first iteration, and you are ignoring `BytesRead` on subsequent iterations. And this code will fail if you ever migrate to D2009+. An alternative to WinInet would be to use Indy's `TIdHTTP` component, it has a `Get()` method that returns the downloed data as a string.

Comment: @dudey: an alternative you could try is wrap `InternetReadFile()` inside of a custom `TStream` class, then use `TStreamReader.ReadLine()` to process the lines while the file is still downloading. That way, you perform the search sooner, you can abort the download when you find the desired line, and you don't waste memory storing the entire file into a single string.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i used before TIdHTTP but wininet geturlfunction is more easy to get - can u give me example of doing with InternetReadFile ? thx

Comment: @dudey: Don't read the entire file especially if you are only searching for a particular string. You already have a read loop in `GetUrlContent` - search the buffer there instead. Yes, the logic is going to be a bit more complex to account for searches that span page boundaries but the performance benefit will be worth it, I think.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError ok after how can show that specific line ?